# IC power supply backup

Tags: voltage, power, current, spi, sram

I'm using this [ic](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/23LCV1024-1Mbit-SPI-Serial-SRAM-with-Battery-Backup-and-SDI-Interface-20005156B.pdf)

The datasheet for the 23LVC1024 SRAM specifies a minimum supply voltage of 2.5V. I want to use a power supply set at 2.5V, but with tolerance that could be less than that, say down to 2.4V. That implies that I could not use this part with the supply that I have designed. However, there is a VTRIP (typically 1.8V) at which the chip switches over to the VBAT supply. This implies that the part will work at some voltages below 2.5V, but I need to know that operation is guaranteed. Can you tell me what happens to the functionality of the part between VCC = 2.5V and VTRIP?

Also shall I connect my 2.5V supply to both Vcc and Vbat pins? Or how it should be connected?

Comment: The datasheet says VDR (voltage data retention) ram retention voltage typically 1V. Ref DS20005156B-page 2. The device will only operate at 2.5V minimum, but will retain the data with vbatt down to 1V.

Comment: The datasheet is pretty clear in terms of the operational parameters, but realise the actual values vary so you need some tolerance otherwise your design will be flaky. Stay away from the grey area.

Comment: Sorry, unable to get you. Could you please write an answer?

Comment: Can I connected my 2.5V supply to both Vcc and Vbat?

Comment: Per the data sheet the battery voltage (Vbat) pin spec is 1.4V to 3.6 V, so connecting it to Vcc (within that range) should be acceptable. There is also this paragraph on page 12, section 3.6, "if the V BAT function is not being used, it is recommended to connect this pin to VSS". However, with that the spec that claims data retention down to 1v sort of implies that you would need to connect the Vbat pin to something since the switch over to the battery power occurs at about 1.8V.  (Microchip data sheet: DS20005156B)

Comment: The chart on page 15 of the data sheet also makes a claim that the Read/Write access operates with Vcc down to the Vtrip level. However this does seem to contradict the basic Vcc spec minimum of 2.5V.  Since there does seem to be a "grey area" it might be best to leave a specific question on the Microchip customer support page to get the best answer,  https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/